# Multiple df with a loop

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I want to create multiple df with a loop

this is my code:

`index_investing= {"S&P 500","Nasdaq 100"}`

for names_index in index_investing:

`df_names_index=investpy.get_index_historical_data(index=names_index, country='United States', from_date='01/01/2005', to_date= '31/12/2020')`

The code returns df_names_index and that is df_Nasdaq 100

how I can make the loop to create :

df_S&P 500 and df_Nasdaq 100

Comment: Dynamically creating variable names is usually a bad idea. Better create a dictionary with the indexes as keys and the dataframes as values.

Comment: could you explain that ?

Comment: Create a dictionary before the loop and add a new entry in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: And how i can do that sorry im newbie

Comment: Then you should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: index= {}
for names_index in index_investing:
    index[names_index]=investpy.get_index_historical_data(index= names_index,
                                                  country='United States',
                                        from_date='01/01/2005',
                                         to_date= '31/12/2020')

Answer (score -2):

The answer to this question is rather simple than it looks.
use

```
for names,index in index_investing
```

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-80d4b26a52ce> in <module>
----> 1 for names,index in index_investing:
      2     df_names_index=investpy.get_index_historical_data(index= names_index,
      3                                                   country='United States',
      4                                         from_date='01/01/2005',
      5                                          to_date= '31/12/2020')

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: What do you expect this to do?